# Who Would Delete All The Developers?

Tags: developer, delete

In a brand new Developer Edition Org I see this in my anonymous execution window.

Now I'm scared.

[image]

Comment: Anyone who wanted to delete the records and had access to them. There is a good book http://www.jkp.com/mindreading that can help you with the "why they did it part". If you want to know who, do a query for the deleted records and inspect the lastmodifiedby field

Comment: that is interesting, if it is indeed a brand new developer edition...!

Comment: Thanks for the mind reading book.  I guess the next question for me is how do I acquire images of the facial expressions of the person who was going to delete all the developers?

Comment: Spotted this myself the other day, must be in the template that DE orgs are made from

Comment: Their most recent template is a bit fubar. It has really no bearing on anything.